# Compile template from another app directory

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have two ember-cli applications, `./my-app` and `./new-app`. In my-app, if I run ember build all my `*.js` files and `*.hbs` files gets compiled and stored as `./my-app/dist/my-app.js`. Now I just want to include one .hbs file inside `./new-app/app/templates` for my-app. For some reason I can't include that .hbs file in my-app. Any way to get it done? Should I have to configure any file?